# Quoting lyrics or lines of poetry

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

When quoting a lyric or line of poetry in running prose, should the original capitalisation be preserved?

Comment: Yes. New lines are separated by slashes: Do not go gentle into that good night, /Old age should burn and rave at close of day; /Rage, rage against the dying of the light.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, the original capitalization should be preserved.

Comment: Right now, this answer reads like personal opinion. If you can support it by adding references to usage guides or other authorities, I'll upvote it.  If not, I'll downvote it.